# Regular Expression - Accept 15 to 17 Digits

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression that accepts numeric only between 15 to 17 digits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`^\d{15,17}$` - For any digit (use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` to avoid Unicode characters, if applicable).
`^[1-9]\d{14,16}$` - If you don't want the number to start with all zeros.

Of course, it might be easier to parse the number and check it, it fits nicely in a `long` value.